# Socrata, find all available datasets

Tags: socrata

I am interested into getting financial open data from any available Socrata dataset. I have managed to get a small java application working for any specific dataset, but i was wondering if there is a way to get all available datasets progammatically.

I wouldn't like to ask the user to enter a url/dataset Id, it would be nice if the program could provide a list for all the datasets given a category.

I know [http://www.opendatanetwork.com](http://www.opendatanetwork.com/), has a big list of such datasets, but i didnt find a way to get this information programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API that powers the Open Data Network is the Socrata Global Search API, and you can find the docs at http://labs.socrata.com/docs/search.html.

Comment: thanks, thats what i needed. i guess i will have to get this `"metadata" : { "domain" : "data.oregon.gov" },` and add the `https://` for it to work, right?

Comment: Yep, `domain` will be the customer domain that the dataset is hosted on!

Answer (score -3):

Use the '$offset=' parameter by setting it to 1000 increments which will allow you to page through the entire dataset 1000 rows at a time.

Another way is to use the '$limit=' parameter which will set a limit on how much you query from a dataset. SODA 2.0 API endpoints have a max limit of 50,000 records while SODA 2.1 endpoints have no upper limit.

`https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/4tka-6guv.json?$limit=50&$offset=150`

This link may be can help you 
https://support.socrata.com/hc/en-us/articles/202949268-How-to-query-more-than-1000-rows-of-a-dataset